# Wordpress plugin pages

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm not sure how to ask this so I'll explain my problem first.  I have a plugin for Wordpress that updates a calendar and some databases that have multiple id's. So I have a hook for a page "editrental.php" which works fine but then when I click on a link for a certain item and goes to something like this 
"editrental.php?id=3828" it won't let the page show.  I'm guessing it has something to do with the way i set up the hook which is like this

```
add_submenu_page(null,'Wasatch Front Waste Calander Manage Editrental', 
'WFWRD Calendar Manage Editrental', 'manage_options', 'trailer-scheduler-
editrental', 'trailer_admin_editrental');
```

Any ideas on how to set this up correctly or links to send me in the right direction? Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to fix this all I ended up doing was switching "editrental.php?id=3828" with "editrental.php&id=3828".  For some reason it wasn't excepting the ? but it did except the &.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
add_submenu_page(
        'edit.php?post_type=POST-TYPE-NAME', //under which post/custom post the submenu should appear
        __('Submenu Title','menu-test'), 
        __('Submenu Title','menu-test'), 
        'manage_options',
        'custom-admin-page',
        array($this, 'function-name') //where the functionality works for the submmenu
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Add to admin_menu function
$page = add_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=theme', __('Theme Page Options'), __('Theme Menu Options'), 'edit_themes', 'theme_options', theme_options);

function theme_options() {
        // Render our theme options page here ...
}
```

[image: theme options]